# How to fix "UNIQUE constraint failed" from VACUUM (also INTEGRITY_CHECK fails)

Tags: sqlite, duplicates, primary-key, unique-constraint, vacuum

I use an app which creates this SQLite DB with this table:

```
CREATE TABLE expense_report (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, ...)
```

And for some reason that _id (which [is the ROWID](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#rowid)) became invalid in that DB.
When I scan the table I see that the last rows got an _id which was already being used long ago:

> 1,2,3...,1137,`1138,...,1147`,1149,...,12263,**12264**,`1138,...,1148`

I highlighted above the ranges in which I see that I have the same _id for completely different rows (the rest of the values do not match at all).

And querying this DB usually gets me inaccurate results due to that. For instance:

```
SELECT
    (SELECT MAX(_ID) FROM expense_report) DirectMax
    , (SELECT MAX(_ID) FROM (SELECT _ID FROM expense_report ORDER BY _ID DESC)) RealMax;

| DirectMax | RealMax |
| 1148      | 12264   |
```

And inserting a new row into this table via [DB Browser for SQLite](https://sqlitebrowser.org/) also generates an _id of `1149` (instead of `12265`), so the problem becomes worse if I keep using this DB.

Running [PRAGMA QUICK_CHECK](https://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_quick_check) or PRAGMA INTEGRITY_CHECK show this error response:

> *** in database main ***
> On page 1598 at right child: Rowid 12268 out of order

And running [VACUUM](https://sqlite.org/lang_vacuum.html) also detects the problem but doesn't seem to be able to fix it:

> Execution finished with errors.
> Result: UNIQUE constraint failed: expense_report._id

Anyone knows a way to fix these duplicate ROWID values?

Answer (score 0):

I initially fixed my problem with that DB just reverting to older backup of that DB.

But today I found that it happened again (to other records), and I finally fixed it via manual editions with `DB Browser for SQLite`.

I have this query to check the IDs of the repeated rows:

```
SELECT _id, COUNT(*) c FROM expense_report GROUP BY _id HAVING c > 1;
```

But this particular query was returning no rows initially. That changed after:

1. Removed the PK from the `expense_report` table.
2. Ran that query to check the IDs of the repeated rows again and now I got:

   ```
    1506    2
    1507    2
    1508    2
   ```
3. Browsed `expense_report` and searched for each of those keys, and found that they all have incorrect values in the amount column and they all began with `2022-12`.
4. Searched for `2022-12` in the amount column.
5. Selected all the results (which are only those 3 bad rows) and deleted them via <kbd>DEL</kbd> key.

Then all the queries posted in the question worked properly.